# How to set DefaultValueAttribute on List<Color> collection property (set default colors)?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, properties, default-value

so i declared List collection property for my custom control, when i'm trying to set DefaultValueAttribute, it's not compile with error:

> *An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter
>   type*

.. what's i/m doing wrong?

```
    private List<Color> _gradientColorList = new List<Color>();
    [CategoryAttribute("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValueAttribute(new List<Color>(new Color[] { Color.FromArgb(116, 194, 225), Color.FromArgb(1, 145, 200), Color.FromArgb(0, 91, 154) }))]
    public List<Color> GradientColorList
    {
        get
        {
            return _gradientColorList;
        }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                if (value == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException();
                if (value == null || value.Count < 2)
                    throw new Exception("Gradient color list count is less than 2.");
                _gradientColorList = value;
                CreateGradientList(GradientColorList);
                Invalidate();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                ExcMessageBox(exc);
            }
        }
    }
```

and one more question, when i adding or removing colors from my GradientColorList collection property in visual studio property editor (color collection editor), **set** block that contains try-catch does not work and i don't know why? how to fix it?

Comment: The worst you can do is to catch exception in property setter to show message box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using DefaultValueAttribute you can assign the gradientColorList as

```
private List<Color> _gradientColorList = new List<Color>(new List<Color>(new Color[] { Color.FromArgb(116, 194, 225), Color.FromArgb(1, 145, 200), Color.FromArgb(0, 91, 154) }));
```

For the second part, whenever you add or remove an entity in the list, the setter is not called. It'll only be called when you assign the value to "GradientColorList". If you are binding this to UI, better use ObserverableCollection which internally triggers the collection changed event when an entity is added or removed.

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler tells you:
You can't create use a `List<>` as parameter for an attribute. 
All parameters you provide to attributes must be constant. That means they should not be changeable. While an array meets this criteria, a dynamic list where you can add / remove items on the fly does not.
Try to create constant with a list, it won't work:

```
const List<Color> COLORS = new List<Color>();
```

**If you want to provide a default value you have those 3 options in my opinion:**

- Set `_gradientColorList` to the default value:

  ```
  private _gradientColorList = new List<Color>(new Color[] { Color.FromArgb(116, 194, 225), Color.FromArgb(1, 145, 200), Color.FromArgb(0, 91, 154) }));
  ```
- Change your get-function to the following:

  ```
  if (_gradientColorList == null)
  {
      return new List<Color>(new Color[] { Color.FromArgb(116, 194, 225), Color.FromArgb(1, 145, 200), Color.FromArgb(0, 91, 154) }));
  }    
  return _gradientColorList;
  ```
- Use array instead of list